# Calling the output of 1 ps1 as primary input in another script

Tags: powershell, ps

Script 1 allows the users to select a device from a list.
Script 2 automates the shutdown or restart of a device.

I am trying to figure out how to take the selected device in Script 1 and execute Script 2 against it.

Script 1

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Select a Computer'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$okButton.Text = 'OK' 
$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
$cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$cancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'Please select a computer:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)
$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$listBox.Height = 80

[void] $listBox.Items.Add(‘ORTECLAB001’)
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('ORTECLAB002’)
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('ORTECLAB003’)
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('ORTECLAB004’)
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('ORTECLAB005')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('ORTECLAB006')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('ORTECLAB007')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('ORTECLAB008')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('ORTECLAB009')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('ORTECLAB010')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('ORTECLAB011')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('ORTECLAB012')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('ORTECLAB013')

$form.Controls.Add($listBox)

$form.Topmost = $true
$result = $form.ShowDialog()
if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $x = $listBox.SelectedItem
    $x
 }
```

Script 2

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

 $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
 $objForm.Text = "Shutdown | Restart"
 $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300) 
 $objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
 $objForm.FormBorderStyle = "FixedSingle"

 $objForm.KeyPreview = $True
 $objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
{$objForm.Close()}})

 $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
 $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(205,220)
 $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
 $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
 $CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
 $objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

 $SButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
 $SButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,220)
 $SButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
 $SButton.Text = "Shutdown"
 $SButton.Add_Click({Stop-Computer -Force})
 $objForm.Controls.Add($SButton)

 $RButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
 $RButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,220)
 $RButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
 $RButton.Text = "Restart"
 $RButton.Add_Click({Restart-Computer -Force})
 $objForm.Controls.Add($RButton)

 $objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
 $objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
 $objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,120)
 $objLabel.Text = "Please ensure you have selected the correct LAC/E Box before proceeding."
 $objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

 $objForm.Topmost = $True

 $objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
 [void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Change line with `$x` to `.\script2.ps1 $x`, and start script2 with `$x=args[0]`, then $x will have your selection.

Comment: This is the results , Any ideas?                                                                                                                        args[0] : The term 'args[0]' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At \10.6.X.253\c$\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Shutdown.ps1:4 char:4
+ $x=args[0]
+    ~~~~~~~